# Prove the following statement that a function is continuos on metric spaces.

Tags: analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space such that every function $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Prove that every function $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous, for every metric space $Y$.

As the first step, what I should do is prove that every subset $A\subset X$ is open, by constructing a function $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ for which $A$ is the preimage of some open set in $\mathbb R$, I dont know what function construct. Any suggestion or help I would appreciate.

Comment: Does the term "characteristic function" ring a bell? (If you're into probability, maybe you call them "indicator function".)